# While loop on SELECT, DELETE ,INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have list of duplicate Transaction IDs and want to insert first the information to table `Customer_Deleted_OrderRecordes` as log then delete them from `Orderstable`.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @Date Datetime
DECLARE @CustomerName nvarchar(90)
DECLARE @ItemID int 
DECLARE @TransactionID int
DECLARE @Invoice int
 
----selecting values------
SELECT 
    @Date = O.date,
    @CustomerName = c.FullName=,
    @ItemID = O.ItemID,
    @TransactionID = O.TransactionID,
    @Invoice = O.Invoice 
FROM
    CustomerTable c
INNER JOIN
    OrdersTable O ON c.ID = O.CustomerId
WHERE 
    O.TransactionID IN (1680339,1680340,1680341,1680342,1680343,1680344,1680345,1680346,1680347,1680348,1680349,1680350,1680351,1680352,1680353,1680354,1680355,1680356,1680357,1680358,1680359)

---This will insert values before deleting as log ---
INSERT INTO Customer_Deleted__OrderRecordes ([Date], [CustomerName], [ItemID], [TransactionID], [Invoice])
VALUES (@date, @CustomerName, @ItemID, @TransactionID, @Invoice)

---This will delete values after inserting

DELETE FROM OrdersTable 
WHERE TransactionID IN (1680339,1680340,1680341,1680342,1680343,1680344,1680345,1680346,1680347,1680348,1680349,1680350,1680351,1680352,1680353,1680354,1680355,1680356,1680357,1680358,1680359)
```

My query only effects one row instead of the all values selected in the select statement. How to write a `while` loop on SELECT, INSERT, DELETE statements?

Comment: your variables can only hold one value, so you shout switch to isnert INTO SELECT see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16   and delete with join https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Why would you do it row by row instead of set based?

Comment: Maybe a case for temporal tables?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you need to declare variables and use a loop, you can just insert with a select and then delete:

```sql
INSERT Customer_Deleted_OrderRecordes
  (Date, CustomerName, ItemID, TransactionID, Invoice)
SELECT O.date, c.FullName, O.ItemID, O.TransactionID, O.Invoice 
FROM CustomerTable c
INNER JOIN OrdersTable O ON c.ID = O.CustomerId
WHERE O.TransactionID IN 
  (1680339, 1680340, 1680341, 1680342, 1680343, 1680344, 1680345,
   1680346, 1680347, 1680348, 1680349, 1680350, 1680351, 1680352,
   1680353, 1680354, 1680355, 1680356, 1680357, 1680358, 1680359)
```

And then just run the delete.

If you need a loop, (in current situation you wont need one), but as you said in comments there can be a situation where you would need to use variables and insert it according to the values, you can do a `while` loop like:

```sql
while @TransactionID < 1680359
begin
    INSERT INTO Customer_Deleted_OrderRecordes (Date, CustomerName, ItemID, TransactionID, Invoice)
    VALUES (@date, @CustomerName, @ItemID, @TransactionID, @Invoice)
    @TransactionID++
end
```

You can also add the `delete` inside the loop before you update the counter variable, so after each inserted row it should delete that row in other table.

But I would highly suggest you not to use a loop when you don't need one, because it would add so much to execution time.

Comment: this answer is not complete, also it should containing a transaction for the commands

Comment: How to while loop In case I save values on O.TransactionID as variable without having values mention on SELECT Statement and WHERE Clause

Comment: @MohammadBastan Why do you need a loop, what are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: @MohammadBastan I can give you a solution with a while loop but please tell me what you'll achieve with it more than using `insert` with `select`. Using `select` is much easier and faster.

Comment: Some times i join tables and get values and set them in variable, but in current situation i already have the transactionid.

Comment: @MohammadBastan See my edit, I added a `while` loop example. But I would highly suggest not to use it when you don't need it.